# combobox "drop down" position on large touch screen

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

Using a simple form with -

```
<select id="title" style="width:80px;" name="title">
  <option value="M.">M.</option>
  <option value="Mme">Mme</option>
</select>
```

on small screen, when touching the screen, I get a list of radio, with the options.

but on large screen, when touching, There is a regular dropdown-list, but its position is not below the opener object. It is displayed on the right side of the screen, quite far from the opener object.

Any solution?

EDIT: According to [HTML Select not working in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884011/html-select-not-working-in-android) , there was a problem with android 2.X.  there, the option were not seen at all.

I tested on Android 4.2.2 Is there still a problem with input select?

Which tool is responsible to show the picker simple-combobox or list of radio buttons?

Edit 2: Chrome bug? [Why is the dropdown box of SELECT tag shown at wrong place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337592/why-is-the-dropdown-box-of-select-tag-shown-at-wrong-place)

Comment: why you tagged `android`?

Comment: because I tested it on android large touch screen

Comment: it has no relation with android programming language.......